# Inequality with roots, a step is not clear!

Tags: inequality, roots

[image]

$$\sqrt{x+3}\le{x+2}$$

$\ x+3\le{x^2+4x+4}$ --> $\ -x^2-4x+4+x+3\le0$ --> $\ x^2+4x+4-x+3\ge0$ --> $\ x^2+3x+1\ge0$

-->

$$\ (-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a$$

-->

$$\ (-3\pm\sqrt{5})/2a$$

-->

The solution is:

$$\ (-\infty, (-3\pm\sqrt{5})/2] U [(-3\pm\sqrt{5})/2, +\infty$$

**FROM HERE**

Divide the inequality in the 2 possible cases:

a. $\ \sqrt{x+3}\le{x+2}$, $\ x+2\ge0$

b. $\ \sqrt{x+3}\le{x+2}$, $\ x+2\lt0$

a)--> same resolution as before, and, $\ x\ge-2$

b)--> since the first component os always $\ge0$: $\ x\in\varnothing$, $\ x\lt-2$

THEN THE CONCLUSION IS OBVIOUS.

I'd like to know what is the general rule to apply with "Divide with 2 possible cases".

1. Why do I have to?
2. How do I know when to do this?

I made everything correct but basically didn’t do half of the exercise :/
***from HERE*** is where starts the part i left.

Thanks to everyone will respond :)

Comment: MathJax is not just preferred, it's necessary, as is your efforts to solve the problem. As is, this question will be closed.

Comment: @RushabhMehta I posted a link for the exercise i tried to resolve... I’ll try with MathJax but it will take some time...

Comment: Short explanations... $a\leq b$ will not imply that $a^2\leq b^2$.  Consider $-3\leq 1$ but $(-3)^2>(1)^2$.  That being said, we are working with a square root here and inequalities at the same time.  This can never make any sort of sense if we allowed complex numbers so we can safely assume that $0\leq \sqrt{x+3}\leq x+2$ and and as a result $x\geq -2$ and we do have that $0\leq a\leq b$ implies that $0\leq a^2\leq b^2$

Comment: As for why $\sqrt{x+3}$ is always non-negative... that is a result of how the square root function is defined in this context.  $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a function from $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ to $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ which satisfies $f(x)^2 = x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with inequalities, I always look at the domain first, it helps me to eliminate unnecessary scenarios. Right off the bat we can restrict the interval of possible solutions to $x+3 \ge 0$ (expression under the root should be non-negative) and $x+2 \ge 0$ (root should be non-negative) or $x \ge -2$. Keeping this in mind, we can square both parts and solve the inequality without fear that we will obtain false solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found your answer more useful, you explained a way of thinking instead of just the solution. It is simple but it can be very helpful so thanks! Anyway I didn't ask for a solution, I asked why sometimes the teacher choose to make those "two cases" and why we have to clarify the case $\ x+2\lt0$ when we know, it is obvious! Is it a more complete way to resolve the inequality? It is somehow useful? :)

Answer (score 0):

We have $$x\geq -3$$ and $$x\geq -2$$ so $$x\geq -2$$
After squaring we get
$$0\le x^2+3x+1$$ and this is
$$0\le (x+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})(x+\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})$$
and from here we get
$$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\le x<\infty)$$